# ZF2/3 catchall route with slug

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I need one route to fetch page content out of my CMS by a slug. I thought I could easy create a configuration like the following but it seems that it only works with multiple parts in the route. My plan was to create a custom route, but if I don't get a match with the system routes I don't think I will get one with my custom route :)

So is there a way to do that?

**Does not work**

```
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'cms' => [
            'type' => \Zend\Router\Http\Segment::class,

            'options' => [
                'route' => '/:slug',

                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => \Cms\Controller\PageController::class,
                    'action' => 'index'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

**Works**

```
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'cms' => [
            'type' => \Zend\Router\Http\Segment::class,

            'options' => [
                'route' => '/test/:slug', // <-- Here is the change

                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => \Cms\Controller\PageController::class,
                    'action' => 'index'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, forgett everything... I already had a segment route with the same format, but with some constraints. Therefore I got a 404 page. So everything works fine...